# I need help arranging div positions using Lost Grid

Tags: html, css

My HTML code is organized in this way:

```
<div class="Container">

    <div class="Card"></div>
    <div class="Card"></div>
    <div class="Card"></div>
    <div class="Card"></div>
    <div class="Card"></div>

</div>
```

And my CSS is organized as such:

```
.Container
    lost-utility clearfix

.Card:first-child
    lost-waffle 1 1 15px

.Card:nth-child(n+2)
    lost-waffle 1/2 2 15px
```

The result looks like the following:

[image]

My issue is that I am trying to get the first div to span 100% of the width, the way it shows in the image, and the rest of the divs to display 1/2 the width. I do not know how to get that second div to the left instead of to the right, and then the third div to the right and up, etc... Basically all the divs after the first div needs to be shifted by 1. I haven't been able to figure this out. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please provide a jsfiddle imitating what you've accomplished.

Comment: @GavinThomas I'm not sure how to do that. Lost grid requires post-css, and I use Stylus as my preprocessor.

Comment: I think Codepen supports this.

Comment: can you post your `lost-utility` and `lost-waffle` classes?

Comment: @GavinThomas So while I was setting up the codepen, I managed to figure it out http://codepen.io/sameeranand/pen/OXGmRV

Comment: Actually although it looks the way I need it to, that seemed to have messed up the ordering of the divs..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is caused by the `cycle` that LostGrid. Because LostGrid uses `:nth-child` as the means to select which elements to style, the top "Card" is the first in the `cycle`, and then the second "Card" takes the second place...when in your layout the second card should start the `cycle` instead of being second.

There are three options I came up with quickly to solve this.

**Option 1**
Use LostGrid and have containing `divs` around the different cards.

**Option 2** Not use LostGrid but instead use the math it provides and create the layout in vanilla `css`.

Here's a CodePen with the three options: http://codepen.io/peterramsing/pen/YWrrjv

I'd lean towards Option 2 as LostWaffle is designed for equal card sizes.

**Option 3?** I included a third option. It works but it has some excess `css` that is outputted. But it's an idea.

---

I haven't run into an issue like this with LostGrid yet as I either use Vanilla `css` for this or would use containing `divs`. LostGrid is an amazing tool to use for creating Grids and it's built to help enhance the existing means that `css` has for creating grids. There are various times when LostGrid isn't the tool to use and with PostCSS it's great because it doesn't add bloat if you only use it a handful of times.

This might, however, be a possible feature add for LostGrid to have a bit more control over the `cycle`. I'll think on it a bit more.

Hopefully that helps and be sure to let me know if you think that `cycle` should have some additional customizations for it in later releases.